# Custom RTE Dropdown in Sitecore 7.0

Tags: telerik, sitecore, rad-controls

My client desires to have a dropdown similar to Symbols Dropdown in the RTE (sitecore version 7.0). The client wants different dropdowns for different symbol types, for example, a dropdown having Greek Symbols Upper case, a dropdown having Greek Symbols Lower case, a dropdown having Mathematical Symbols and a dropdown having Other/Misc types of symbols.

I have tried to understand how RadControls work and how to add this on Telerik RadControl but I am unable to map the concept to sitecore's rich text editor. Additionally, I have tried to understand how existent Symbols Dropdown in RTE works but since its code is embedded in Sitecore.Client dll I cant understand much from it.

Can some one please detail the steps to achieve this?

Thanks, 
Vaibhav.

Comment: This other question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485295/sitecore-create-drop-down-button-in-rte-populated-from-master-database

Answer (score 5):

You can add your own custom drop list or drop button to the RTE.

Switch to the `core` database and add a new button in the toolbar of the RTE profile you are using (e.g. `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full/Toolbar 1`)

Make sure the template of the button is of type `Html Editor Custom Drop Down` or `Html Editor Custom Drop Down Button`, these can be found in `/sitecore/templates/System/Html Editor Profiles`. Give a name in the 'Click' field, e.g. InsertCustomSymbols

Add child items to your button to create the "symbols" or text you need using `Html Editor List Item` template. The 'Header' value is what will be displayed in the dropdown list and 'Value' is what will get inserted (e.g. your greek symbols).

[image: Sitecore RTE Profile]

You now need to handle the click event of the button, create a file with the following JS:

```
RadEditorCommandList["InsertCustomSymbols"] = function(commandName, editor, args) {
  var val = args.get_value();
  editor.pasteHtml(val);
  args.set_cancel(true);
}
```

[Create a patch config](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) to add the JS file:

```
<clientscripts>
   <htmleditor>
     <script src="/location/to/custom.js" language="javascript" key="customJs" />
   </htmleditor>
</clientscripts>
```

If you used the Drop Down Button then also add a css style to set the icon, it should also be the same name as the 'Click' field.

```
<style type="text/css">                        
  span.InsertCustomSymbols
  {
    background-image:url('/path/to/icon.gif');                                                                
  }
</style>
```

[image: RTE Custom list]

I didn't style it but you get the idea. Add as many as you need, make sure you [set the correct RTE profile](http://markstiles.net/Blog/2011/03/15/rich-text-editor-profiles.aspx).

You can find a bit more info in this [Telerik Custom Dropdown demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/customdropdowns/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: Excellent. This looks comprehensive. Infact most of the information you put in are the one's which I had been through already; but I was unable to connect all dots.

Let me try this and I will update this post with success/failure status.

Comment: Great, I [wrote up a blog post](http://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/add-custom-drop-down-list-to-rich-text-editor-in-sitecore/) with a little more info.

Comment: Quick question, I followed the steps you mentioned and I could get the dropdown on RTE. But I am unable to see any items (child items on it). Did you miss telling me something or did I miss anything here?

These are the items I have created in my RTE-Core db. 

![New dropdown button][1]


![enter image description here][2]


And this is what comes in RTE.

![enter image description here][3]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QRb3q.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oCeym.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HjtnR.png


I am definitely missing something here. Please help and validate this.

Comment: Let me try reading your blog-post above. May be i may have missed something.

Comment: I am still stuck. I checked all permissions and as well as all paths in configs and css. Every thing looks fine. I dont have anything relevant shown in console of browser too (chrome). Why arent the child items so created shown? Do i have to write additional lines of code to iterate through the child items as mentioned in Telerik's blog?

Comment: Strange. My sample code was done in 7.0 so it's definitely supported (from 6.6 at least in fact). Double check the child template is `Html Editor List Item` or you could create your own `EditorConfiguration` which will allow you to debug it at least http://pastebin.com/juSTp8qn

Comment: I'm having the same issue (no list items appearing), was this ever solved?