# Sitecore 8:Custom Dropdown List in RTE

Tags: sitecore, dropdownlistfor, rte, sitecore8

I am trying to implement a custom drop list in RTE in Sitecore 8.The drop list on selection should just insert the associated value of the selected item from the drop list to RTE.

I followed the blog post at https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/add-custom-drop-down-list-to-rich-text-editor-in-sitecore/  and [Custom RTE Dropdown in Sitecore 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246306/custom-rte-dropdown-in-sitecore-7-0) to implement this.However it does not work in sitecore 8.

Can you please let me know on how to achieve the same.

Thanks In Advance,

Comment: I haven't tried in SC8, what exactly does not work? Is there an error or it just does not show?

Comment: It does not show up :(

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and it's still working the same in Sitecore 8 as it previously did in Sitecore 7.x versions, just as I previously answered and blogged.

Since the change is not showing up then there are some things to check:

- Make sure you are editing the correct Rich Text Profile, there are several defined by default. Check your config for `HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile` setting for the default profile in use
- Make sure your template is has not set a different profile to use. Check the `source` value of the Rich Text field on the template to make sure it does not override the default.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this works in Sitecore 8 as I implemented the same thing following @[jammykam's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661447/jammykam) blog.

Double check your custom drop down is of template `/sitecore/templates/System/Html Editor Profiles/Html Editor Custom Drop Down` or `/sitecore/templates/System/Html Editor Profiles/Html Editor Custom Drop Down Button` 
and your list items are of template `/sitecore/templates/System/Html Editor Profiles/Html Editor List Item`